# New to solidity, Need some tips

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I'm entirely new to solidity and all this cryptographic stuff. I'm interested to learn more, I deployed a couple of contracts with the help of the internet. What's the best way to practice solidity? Need some advice :)

Comment: Shameless plug: These posts were created to help new devs re-orient for Solidity. https://medium.com/@robhitchens

Answer (score 1):

Started learning about a year ago so still remember pretty well what that period was like. What helped me a lot was the patrick collins videos, solidity by example, mastering ethereum, and digging through project githubs just to look at their code and how they do things.

These are great and will help but the best way was just building different things, making mistakes, getting stuck and then looking for solutions to specific problems. This was what really made the difference for my own personal learning process.

Comment: I would add the Ethernaut CTF to that list. https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/

Answer (score 1):

The Remix IDE is the best place to start.

https://remix.ethereum.org

Start with the templates, work through the code line by line and try and understand what each function does. There's no shame in looking up lines of code or error messages.

The best way is to build yourself so you understand the process.

Answer (score 1):

This Course is the way to go, 32 hours of everything you need:

- Basics (blockchain general knowledge)
- Solidity
- Testing
- Implement in frontend
- and more...

The course was formulated by Patrick Collins, a crazy smart contract guy at Chainlink with tons and tons of experience

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyMwXuJrbJQ